# How to pass parameters to a container orchestrated by Kubernetes similar to running the container at the command line using the docker run command?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, configuration, orchestration

**Background**

I have a docker container that I run in the following fashion:

`docker run --rm my-custom-container:latest --username me --password yes --url "https://my.url"`

The container does what what it needs to do with no issues.

I have pushed my container image to a private image repository, and I am able to create a Kubernetes deployment. Kubernetes is able to pull the container from the private image repository for the container with no problems.

**Problem**

However, when Kubernetes goes to start the container it returns with an error stating that it cannot run the container.

This is due to a lack of parameters being passed to the container to run.

**Question**

How do I pass parameters to my container during a Kubernetes deployment?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the arguments in the deployment yaml.  The [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/) include examples and further customization.

```
spec:
   containers:
     image: myimage
     name: myContainerName
     args: ["me", "yes", "https://my.url"]
```